# Using 'boot' to calculate bootstrapped mean in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I want to use the R command 'boot' to calculate a bootstrapped mean. This doesn't work, though, and always returns the error message:

```
Error in mean.default(data, original, ...) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 <- c(0,159028,236220,9127,0,0),
  v2 <- c(13, 42, 56, 9, 77, 34)
)

boot(df$v1, statistic = mean, R = 100)
```

Which returns the aforementioned error.

Why won't this command work? What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `statistic` should be a function that takes two arguments: the first should be the data to be sampled, and the second should be the indices that `boot` will use to subset your data. Since you are directly passing `mean` to the `statistic` argument, a vector of indices is being passed to the second argument of `mean.default`, which is `trim`. This argument expects a single number, and throws an error when passed a vector.

You need to create a little wrapper function that shows `boot` how you want it to subset your data for sampling:

```r
boot(df$v1, statistic = function(x, inds) mean(x[inds]), R = 100)
#>
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#>
#>
#> Call:
#> boot(data = df$v1, statistic = function(x, inds) mean(x[inds]), 
#>     R = 100)
#>
#>
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>     original   bias    std. error
#> t1* 67395.83 839.4583    39734.55
```